# How to get image data from a WebView into an NSData object?

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsdata, nsimage

I have a Cocoa app that embeds a WebView. The WebView loads html elements including images. I have the textual links for the images (e.g. "http://www.domain.com/path/image.jpg"), but what I want is the image data itself so I can put it in an NSData object and ship it off to Growl. The WebView must have this data since it has downloaded and rendered the image. How can I get at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Get [the web view's main frame](https://web.archive.org/web/20100819162807/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/mainFrame).
2. Get [the frame's data source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100819162807/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebFrame/dataSource).
3. [Ask the data source for the downloaded resource for the image URL.](https://web.archive.org/web/20100819162807/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebDataSource_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebDataSource/subresourceForURL:)
4. Get [the resource's data](https://web.archive.org/web/20100819162807/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebResource_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebResource/data).

Comment: Thank you! I thought this had to be possible, but I had no idea how to do it and probably wouldn't have figured it out. Thanks for Growl, too. It's awesome.

Comment: On behalf of all Growl developers past and present, you're welcome. ☺